# Integrate SimplyPost with Magento store

Tags: api, web-services, shipment-tracking

Does anyone try integrating [SimplyPost](http://simplypost.asia/platform/) with Magento, Is there any plugins or giudes I can follow? So far I could find only the SimplyPost [API](http://developer.simplypost.asia/#overview). I'm new to magento, So have no idea where to start. I will appreciate any kick-start.
Peace!

Comment: http://simplypost.asia/platform/ I just opened this website, i think they are providing an extension for Magento, Shopify, and WooCommerce as per the website.

Comment: I notice that, but they just mention the platform "Magento". there is nothing more details than that. Even in Google I couldn't find any extension or guides regarding this. Strange.

Comment: You purchased their service ,if yes then they will surely tell you ,Just contact them http://simplypost.asia/contact-us/  . I am 100% sure that they have extensions .

Comment: Otherwise you have to create your own custom module ,using their API

Comment: I haven't purchase yet, I need to confirm before subscribe to their service. Yea I send a note too. I need to research more on creating custom modules as-well, but do thing their API is good enough to do the job?

Comment: I never worked on SimplePost, still you have to contact them.

Comment: Meanwhile read their API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage write an custom module to connect SimplyPost with Magento via RESTful API. I Just wanna share the code. Check [Github](https://github.com/krrishnajee/MageSimplyPost) to find the complete source.

1- app/code/local/Mymodule/Simplypost/etc/config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mymodule_Simplypost>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Mymodule_Simplypost>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <simplypost>
                <class>Mymodule_Simplypost_Model</class>
            </simplypost>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <simplypost>
                <class>Mymodule_Simplypost_Helper</class>
            </simplypost>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <simplypost>
                <class>Mymodule_Simplypost_Block</class>
            </simplypost>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <!--call simplypost process before save shipment-->
        <events>
            <sales_order_shipment_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <create_simplypost>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>simplypost/observer</class>
                        <method>createSimplypost</method>
                    </create_simplypost>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_shipment_save_before>
        </events>
        <!--customize the grid on order view page to show the SimplyPost tracking status-->
        <events> 
            <core_block_abstract_to_html_after>
                <observers>
                    <simplypost_custom_order_view_info>
                        <class>simplypost/observer</class>
                        <method>getSalesOrderViewInfo</method>
                    </simplypost_custom_order_view_info>
                </observers>
            </core_block_abstract_to_html_after>
        </events>
        <!--create a custom grid on order view page : app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/mymodule_simplypost.xml -->
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <simplypost>
                    <file>mymodule_simplypost.xml</file>
                </simplypost>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

2- app/code/local/Mymodule/Simplypost/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php
/*
*   Observer Event : sales_order_shipment_save_before
*   This is the function which post data SimplyPost
*/
class Mymodule_Simplypost_Model_Observer {

    public function createSimplypost(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

        $shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();
        $order = $shipment->getOrder();

        //This can be serve from admin cms, check the Github link for more details
        $spEnable = true;
        $spAuthEndpoint = https://app.simplypost.asia/api/gateway/v1/auth/login/;
        $spLoginToken = 'Basic weloYUBasd313WEdfsf23423429tOnhwbzEyMw==';
        $spEndpoint = 'https://app.simplypost.asia/api/gateway/v1/deliveries/';
        $spMerchantCode = 'W2134';
        $spServiceCode = 'DOMN';

        if($spEnable){

            //check all configurations exists
            if($spAuthEndpoint == null || $spLoginToken == null || $spEndpoint == null || $spMerchantCode == null || $spServiceCode == null){

                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('SimplyPost failed, Configurations Error.');
                //stop the process
                Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
                Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
                exit;

            }
            else{

                // get all order items and make an array
                $orderitems = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
                $arrItem = array();
                $arrItems = array();
                foreach ($orderitems as $orderitem): 
                    $product = $orderitem->getProduct();
                    $arrItem['weight'] = ($product->getData('weight')) ? $product->getData('weight') : 0;
                    $arrItem['description'] = ($product->getData('short_description')) ? $product->getData('short_description') : 0;
                    $arrItem['weight_unit'] = "Kg";
                    $arrItems[] = $arrItem;
                    unset($arrItem);
                endforeach;

                /*
                 * Send data to Simplypost via Zend_Http_Client
                */
                //genarate new token, because this token is only valid for 1 hour
                $auth = $spLoginToken;
                $clientLogin = new Zend_Http_Client();
                $clientLogin->setHeaders(array(
                    'Authorization' => $auth
                ));
                $clientLogin->setUri($spAuthEndpoint);
                $clientLogin->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::POST);
                $responseLogin = $clientLogin->request();
                if ($responseLogin->isSuccessful()) {

                    $responseLogin = json_decode($responseLogin->getBody());
                    //our new token
                    $token = "JWT ".$responseLogin->token;

                    //end point post order details to simplypost
                    $url = $spEndpoint;
                    //obj Zend_Http_Client
                    $client = new Zend_Http_Client();
                    //set Authentication and other headers
                    $client->setHeaders(array(
                        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                        'Authorization' => $token
                    ));
                    //set endpoint url
                    $client->setUri($url);

                    //create post data into SimplyPost array format
                    $customerFName = ($order->getShippingAddress()->getData('firstname')) ? $order->getShippingAddress()->getData('firstname') : null;
                    $customerLName = ($order->getShippingAddress()->getData('lastname')) ? $order->getShippingAddress()->getData('lastname') : null;
                    $customerAddressStreet = ($order->getShippingAddress()->getData('street')) ? $order->getShippingAddress()->getData('street') : null;
                    $customerAddressCity = ($order->getShippingAddress()->getData('city')) ? $order->getShippingAddress()->getData('city') : null;
                    $customerAddressCountry = ($order->getShippingAddress()->getData('country_id')) ? Mage::app()->getLocale()->getCountryTranslation($order->getShippingAddress()->getData('country_id')) : null;
                    $data = array(
                        'merchant_code'  => $spMerchantCode, // copied from SimplyPost Mymodule account
                        'reference_number'   => ($order->getData('increment_id')) ? $order->getData('increment_id') : null, // order number
                        'order_source'   => 'mage_test', //random string
                        'service_code'   => $spServiceCode, //Delievery stype code
                        "pickup_details" => array( //Pickup details from admin cms
                            "contact_name" => "Kevin",
                            "phone_number" => '12344321',
                            "email" => 'kev@gmail.com',
                            "address" => 'Address goes here',
                            "postcode" => '123443',
                            ),
                        'consignee_details' => array( //Customer details
                            "contact_name" => $customerFName." ".$customerLName,
                            "phone_number" => ($order->getShippingAddress()->getData('telephone')) ? $order->getShippingAddress()->getData('telephone') : null,
                            "email" => ($order->getShippingAddress()->getData('email')) ? $order->getShippingAddress()->getData('email') : null,
                            "address" => $customerAddressStreet." ".$customerAddressCity." ".$customerAddressCountry,
                            "postcode" => ($order->getShippingAddress()->getData('postcode')) ? $order->getShippingAddress()->getData('postcode') : null,
                            ),
                        'item_details' => $arrItems,
                    );
                    //set the parameters
                    $client->setParameterPost($data);

                    // POST request
                    $client->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::POST);
                    $response = $client->request();
                    if ($response->isSuccessful()) {
                        //decode the response
                        $responseBody = json_decode($response->getBody());

                        // update the tracking code into shipment in our system
                        $shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();
                        $track = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')
                            ->setNumber($responseBody->tracking_id) //tracking number / awb number
                            ->setCarrierCode('simplypost') //carrier code
                            ->setTitle('SimplyPost'); //carrier title
                        $shipment->addTrack($track);
                        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Order added to the SimplyPost.');


                    }
                    else{
                        //log error
                        Mage::log($response);
                        $responseBody = json_decode($response->getBody());
                        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('SimplyPost Failed: '.$responseBody->error->message);
                        //stop the process
                        Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
                        Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
                        exit;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    //log error
                    Mage::log($responseLogin);
                    $responseLogin = json_decode($responseLogin->getBody());
                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('SimplyPost Authentication Failed: '.$responseLogin->errors);
                    //stop the process
                    Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
                    Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
                    exit;
                }
            }
        }


    }

    // This function is called on core_block_abstract_to_html_after event
    // We will append our block to the html in the adminhtml under order page
    public function getSalesOrderViewInfo(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $block = $observer->getBlock();
        // layout name should be same as used in app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/mymodule.xml
        if (($block->getNameInLayout() == 'order_info') && ($child = $block->getChild('simplypost.order.info.custom.block'))) {
            $transport = $observer->getTransport();
            if ($transport) {
                $html = $transport->getHtml();
                $html .= $child->toHtml();
                $transport->setHtml($html);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Great to see that you did it

Comment: Thanks man, as you say I just follow their API and build a custom module :)